# Basic card authentication protocol

Tags: smartcard, basic

I'm working on my authentication protocol on basic card and I don't know how to generate random number with max. size 160bits. Do you have any experience with that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Rnd` built-in function. Citing the [documentation](http://209.68.36.204/downloads/bc_pdf.zip) (section 3.19):

> The **Rnd** built-in function returns a 4-byte random number. The Terminal and the various BasicCards 
>   have different mechanisms for random number generation.

So to get 160 random bits (20 random bytes) call this function five times.

---

An additional note:

- Beware that only The Professional and MultiApplication BasicCards do have a true RNG!

---

Disclaimer: I am not proficient with BasicCard so please do validate my thoughts...

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate, would you mind if i ask you some more things? Can i contact you with e-mail for example?

Comment: @tom9999 I am afraid I can't help you very much with BasicCard as I have a very limited experience with it (my former colleague only evaluated it and we did not use it in any project)..Good luck!